# Where could I find further documentation for the method set_iam_policy of the google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

I try to use the [set_iam_policy](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.projects.ProjectsClient#google_cloud_resourcemanager_v3_services_projects_ProjectsClient_set_iam_policy) method of the GCP python library `google-cloud-resource-manager`, but I'm unable to find appropriate documentations about the expected input. The documentation [notes](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.projects.ProjectsClient#google_cloud_resourcemanager_v3_services_projects_ProjectsClient_set_iam_policy) to use a `google.iam.v1.iam_policy_pb2.SetIamPolicyRequest` as input for `request` but `SetIamPolicyRequest` is not linked / described. Does anyone  know how to get more information about `google.iam.v1.iam_policy_pb2.SetIamPolicyRequest`.
[image]

Ideally, there is a hyperlink which provides further information, as seen in the following picture.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received from the GCP support the following URL:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.iam.v1#google.iam.v1.SetIamPolicyRequest

The website delivers the documentation for `SetIamPolicyRequest`, but not that detailed. For example, the field `resource` is not described what it should be. It worked for me that way: `"resource": f"projects/{project_id}"`